# Chances of German work visa rejection

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I'm currently working in India. I have got a work offer from a German company and they have sent me the contract. I need to now apply for a work visa from here.

I have got the offer as a software developer and the salary is above 42k€. I have a graduation in engineering and it is equivalent in the ANABIN database. I have an overall experience of 4years 8 months.

Can anyone let me know what are the chances of visa rejection? If there are chances what might be the reason. Are there any particular instructions someone can give so that I can get the visa 100%?

Comment: AFAIK you can ask your prospective employer to get pre-approval https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17982/what-are-steps-for-getting-zav-certificat but as with any visa application I do not think there is anything you can do that will 100% guarantee success

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are other unknown facts not mentioned (such as a criminal record), based on given information your chances look good. Giving a 100% solution is not possible.

Some thoughts, tips that **may** assist you (or other readers) getting *near* 100%:

Immigration to another country is an important affair, so prepare yourself properly.

Study the requirements of the country you want to move to. 
Work out the best Visa type that fits your situation.

Create a checklist and work though it point by point

- the main points have to be documented anyway as part of the application
- some points may, however (in the eyes of the Immigration / Cousulate official) not be clear and should be addressed

A short, clear and documented summary that will clarify anything that (for them) may be doubtful

- if they know the **worst** about you and **deem it irrelevant**

  - then you’re good (now and in the long term)

---

Each country has it's own **quirks**, often difficult to learn beforehand.

Getting certain documents while still in your home country may make your life easier later.

Here a short (definitely **not** complete) list for Germany that may well be true for others:

**Birth certificate**
Assume at any unexpected moment a demand will be made for a **certified** translated version of your birth certificate.

So while you are still in you home country, get an **English** certified translation of your Birth certificate.

With that, sometime after your arrival in Germany, get that translated to German. (Needed for Marriage or Nationalization)

Assume an English to German translation will be cheaper than another language to German

- that in itself is expensive enough

**Marriage status/history**
Verified proof is required for a marriage in Germany.
The marriage process is generally considered the most horrific experience our *beloved* bureaucracy has to offer.
For foreigners more so, since the marriage status must be retrieved from their home country.

**Criminal record**
Called **Führungszeugnis** of which there are 3 types:

- simple, extended (erweitertes) and confidential

Since **correction** (as opposed to **punishment**) is the goal of the legal system, a **simple** will not contain entries for events that have expired

- no repeat of event (or something similar to) in the last five years is considered to have expired and therefore no longer relevant

An **extended** will contain expired entries

- for any job dealing with children this form is required

High level jobs and (I believe) the founding of a business will require one or the other.

Only a judge or state attorney may view the **confidential** version which may contain information about charges that do not lead to a conviction (only a previous judge may decide if such an entry is made).

For foreigners this can be problematic since any events outside of Germany will not be recorded.
The procurement of some local equivalent (again certified in English) beforehand may come in handy later.

For someone without a record, **no entries** (Keine Eintragung) is what the Führungszeugnis will say.

Submitting this (unrequested) information with the application may also have the advantages of the Consulate official (who should be familiar with the local situation) adding a note:

- this certificate from country X corresponds to our Führungszeugnis type Y

Remember also that when your application is being processed, it will not be done in your home country and thus by someone who might not be familiar on how things are done in your country.
So trying to get things in a form they understand will make **your life** easier.

---

Hope this helps in getting nearer to the 100%, not only for your application but also during you stay.