# What are steps for getting ZAV certificat?

Tags: germany, schengen, internship

I'm Amit Kumar Ghosh from Bangladesh. I'm studying Automobile Engineering in India. Right now I'm in 4th year. I got internship offer from one company in Germany. I heard about ZVA certificate. Without this i will not get my visa. But i dont have any idea about ZAV certificate. Can anybody help me to clarify about ZAV certificate? 
Thank You

Comment: Ask the company.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://immigrate-to-germany.blogspot.com/2018/06/what-is-a-zav-or-fea-approval-for-germany-work-permit-and-how-to-get-it.html?m=1 ZAV is a service from the Federal Employment Agency (FEA), which regulates employment in Germany. ZAV regulates the hiring of foreign workers; it is required for non-Blue Card visa applications.

You can ask your employer to get a ZAV approval for you and submit the ZAV Letter with your application. Or you can apply and the ZAV validation will be done as part of processing the visa application. The first approach is typically quicker.